# NoClassDefFoundError with Gradle

Tags: java, gradle

When I run gradle tests in Intellij (or using `./gradlew test`, I get `NoClassDefFoundError`.

When I run gradle dependencies, I see:

```
testRuntimeOnly - Runtime only dependencies for source set 'test'. (n)
No dependencies
```

even though I have some test-only dependencies in my build file.  I'm also not able to import a class from the onebiz:datastore_testing project.

I'm running JDK 11

build.gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'jacoco'

apply from: "$rootDir/standard-java.gradle"
apply from: "$rootDir/standard-java-publishing.gradle"


ext.googleCloudClientSpannerVersion='6.28.0'

dependencies {
    compile "com.google.cloud:google-cloud-spanner:$googleCloudClientSpannerVersion"
    compile (project(":onebiz:onebiz"))

    testCompile "org.mockito:mockito-core:$onebiz_MOCKITO"
    testCompile "junit:junit:$onebiz_JUNIT"
    testCompile project(":onebiz:datastore_testing")
}

test {
    finalizedBy jacocoTestReport
}

jacocoTestReport {
    dependsOn test
}

jacocoTestCoverageVerification {
    violationRules {
        rule {
            limit {
                minimum = 0.8
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Error message:

```
    Could not initialize class com.s.onebiz.util.TestUtils
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class com.s.onebiz.util.TestUtils
    at com.s.onebiz.util.TestClientManager.<init>(TestClientManager.java:39)
    at com.s.onebiz.core.cloud.spanner.CloudSpannerOneDataImplTest.<clinit>(CloudSpannerOneDataImplTest.java:38)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:59)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:56)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.invokeMethod(RunBefores.java:33)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:24)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunAfters.evaluate(RunAfters.java:27)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:306)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:413)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.junit.JUnitTestClassExecutor.runTestClass(JUnitTestClassExecutor.java:110)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.junit.JUnitTestClassExecutor.execute(JUnitTestClassExecutor.java:58)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.junit.JUnitTestClassExecutor.execute(JUnitTestClassExecutor.java:38)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.junit.AbstractJUnitTestClassProcessor.processTestClass(AbstractJUnitTestClassProcessor.java:62)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.SuiteTestClassProcessor.processTestClass(SuiteTestClassProcessor.java:51)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:36)
    at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:24)
    at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ContextClassLoaderDispatch.dispatch(ContextClassLoaderDispatch.java:33)
    at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ProxyDispatchAdapter$DispatchingInvocationHandler.invoke(ProxyDispatchAdapter.java:94)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy5.processTestClass(Unknown Source)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.worker.TestWorker.processTestClass(TestWorker.java:119)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:36)
    at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:24)
    at org.gradle.internal.remote.internal.hub.MessageHubBackedObjectConnection$DispatchWrapper.dispatch(MessageHubBackedObjectConnection.java:182)
    at org.gradle.internal.remote.internal.hub.MessageHubBackedObjectConnection$DispatchWrapper.dispatch(MessageHubBackedObjectConnection.java:164)
    at org.gradle.internal.remote.internal.hub.MessageHub$Handler.run(MessageHub.java:414)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:64)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ManagedExecutorImpl$1.run(ManagedExecutorImpl.java:48)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ThreadFactoryImpl$ManagedThreadRunnable.run(ThreadFactoryImpl.java:56)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)
```

Comment: Is that "onebiz:datastore_testing" project part of the same Gradle multi-module build/project? If so, does that dependency work with other sub-midules?

Comment: @Dimitry Khamitov, yes it is. It does work with other submodules.  Things broke after I added this dependency.